# fontWeight attribute not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to set the font-weight of a text in Jetpack Compose and it's just not doing any effect.
I can see the change in the preview, but nothing changes when I run the app.

I updated everything possible.

for example, even the simplest text font weight change isn't working:

```
Text(
       fontWeight = FontWeight(800),
       text = "Text Example",
    )
```

I've also tried putting the fontWeight after the text attribute — the same result.

What could be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Your code should work

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I know but for some reason it does not. Still haven't figured why. To me, it seems now like a very frustrating bug

Answer (score 1):

Clean and Rebuild the project.
So your code will work perfectly

> **Font weight can be in the range [1 to 1000]**

```
Text(text = "Text Example", fontWeight = FontWeight(800))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it first thing but it doesn't; want to work. I left it as is for now as I spend already to much time on it, and will come back for this later

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work?

```
Text(
  text = "Text Example",
  style = TextStyle(
      fontWeight = FontWeight(800)))
```

Comment: Nope... I had a feeling that it will actually work. So strange that I can't figure this out.